# How to animate activity when showing dialog

Tags: android, android-animation, android-dialogfragment, android-transitions

When I enter a screen in my app, I use custom animation to slid old fragment out of the screen and slid new one into it. Problematic thing is that when I use a full screen dialog, I can only animate it entering onto the screen, when I also want to animate the old fragment leaving. I tried using transaction and setting custom animation but it only affects dialog fragment. (As its entrance is the only "transaction" being really performed)

Comment: Please post the relevant code

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want to be using a full screen dialog then.

Comment: This was initially a bottom sheet with two-screen flow inside of it, but since navigation in bottom sheet is a hack, we decided to make it into two separate fragments. They collect info from user, but depending on where in the app the user is, use it for different tasks, so having a dialog with can be show over any fragment and utilize their viewmodel to handle retrieved data made sense... up until I had to animate the transitions.